# Jailbroken iPod Touch (5th generation) erase all content & settings problems.

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I’m on the iPod Touch (5th generation)—that is a jailbroken device—and did an erase all content and settings an was. I followed all kinds of steps but it didn’t work because I got to the restore part but there is an update that came out and I can’t restore without updating.

When I try restoring and update the update is first and can’t go past that. The error says

> There was a problem downloading the software for the iPod ipod network
>   connection was reset make sure your network settings are correct and
>   your network connection is active, or try again later.

I’ve been trying over and over but same thing happens.

Comment: Are you having trouble erasing the device or restoring a backup? Is the iPod in recovery mode (as explained here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263)? Have you had a look at these guides? To reset a device: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559 To restore a previous backup: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203977

Answer (score 1):

Unless your previous iOS was 8.1.3 you have no option but to update to 8.2. [& that will change within a few days.]

Apple stops signing old iOS updates very soon after the release of a new one.

It will only still sign an older iOS if that is the latest one your device is capable of running.

If you are having difficulty downloading the ipsw file, you could use a different downloader & use the links posted on [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2015/03/09/ios-8-2-released-ipsw-download/) - these are direct links to the Apple site.

Answer (score 0):

That didn't work either
It won't update and restore even on iTunes with my laptop 
Problem is it won't turn on at all unless it has the apple logo and the bar under but the bar doesn't move at all.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post.